# Swift: Converting this Objective C Method

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Very new to iOS and not too sure what I am doing wrong here...
I am following [this tutorial](http://gibbon.co/psy2k/ios-programming-for-beginners/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections) to build an accordion style UITableView, the author seems to have implemented a delegate function which extends `UITableViewController`.  The tutorial does not conform to any delegates, therefore I can only assume that you are able to directly write extensions.

The original code is:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section>0) return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

After analysing this I constructed the following in Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canCollapseSection section: Int) -> Bool {
    if section > 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I know its a very simple function, but I'd like to get this func working as an extension of the base TableView functions provided.  Currently XCode does not recognise this function when I call it like

`self.tableView.canCollapseSection(tableView, indexPath.section)`

Comment: My current workaround is to do it as you suggested, I may be overlooking the obvious - but I believe the original objective C code has been written as a `UITableViewMethod` or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it like

```
self.tableView(tableView, canCollapseSection: indexPath.section)
```

Comment: That's fixed it, is it just me or is XCode 6 very bad at updating its suggestion list?  The method was not their earlier, I have now restarted XCode and it appeared under the `tableView` methods...very strange.